# What php does my windows server run? Tomcat and/or Apache and how are they related?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, tomcat, windows-server-2012

I have a Windows Server 2012 VPS at Strato. 
I've installed a domain and set PHP 5.2.17 to be executed as FastCGI in Plesk.
I uploaded code that used to work on another Windows server.

Now I run into some problems and the solutions I find on the internet always assume you have Apache. For instance, I want to test a setting in httpd.conf to see if it solves my problem. But I cannot find any directory on my system where Apache could be, nor can I find a file named httpd.conf. Another problem is that .htaccess seems to be neglected.

I do find a folder named Tomcat under Plesk\Additional so I assume I have Tomcat. 
- How is Tomcat technically related to Apache? 
- How can I run PHP so all Apache things work? Like httpd.conf and .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Apache is the organisation that maintains Apache Tomcat and Apache HTTPD.

Apache Tomcat is a HTTP server designed to run Java Servlets and JSP programs.

It has no connection to Apache HTTPD other than being maintained by the same organisation.

It isn't configured through `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` and it is not compatible with `mod_php`.

Comment: So what causes PHP to be executed on this server? Tomcat?

Comment: You are most likely running PHP's own web server.

Comment: @user3260382 — At the moment, since you don't appear to be successfully running any PHP, it sounds like "nothing".

Comment: I forgot to mention that PHP does run, only with the url rewrite error. So .htaccess only works on Apache? Should I install this or hire a new server with linux just to be safe?

Comment: `.htaccess` is a means to override the configuration of an Apache HTTPD server on a directory by directory basis. I think a couple of other servers have taken up the format, Apache Tomcat is not one of them.

Comment: Since you don't seem to know how your server is set up, I'd advise against installing new software on it until you understand how it is currently configured. If you can't get comfortable administering the server, then switching to one you are more familiar with might be a good idea.